# Convergence criteria for Active contour model

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

Currently, active contour convergence is checked visually.

So how can we set a convergence criteria?

I looked into some unsupervised segmentation method for image segmentation but couldn't got a proper criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a pre-defined maximum number of iterations. Moreover, you could limit the minimum update of the level-set. That is, the total evolution at a given time-step should exceed a threshold $\tau$. Otherwise you stop. It is also possible to interpret this as a norm in the update of the derivative (e.g. second derivative).